# ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream Issue

Tags: java, spring

I have the following code.

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.load(ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("ui.properties"));
```

I am running a Maven build, so this file is under

src/main/resources.

When I build the file and run the application the Input Stream is null.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you build? war file? Can you open it and check that this file is included?

Comment: When I open the war, I see WEB-INF/classes/ui.properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you try

```
props.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("ui.properties"));
```

instead of

```
props.load(ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("ui.properties"));
```

Comment: I think this is probably the answer. But I am getting the following error now: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getClass()

Comment: then maybe use the class name instead of getClass() e.g. MyClass.getClassLoader().getRes ... or move that line to a non-static method

Answer (score 1):

Try an absolute path, like "/ui.properties" (or wherever the file is in the output classes or jar file).